# Why cant I get any kind of traffic from my AWS EC2 instance with a public IP?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, deployment, node.js

*Complete beginner to networking and im trying to deploy a simple express app on a windows instance of ec2 and I cannot find a single resource that explains the steps I need to take to make it happen without having a ton of technical terms and people getting angry and downvoting (and even removing my question from stack overflow for being too "vague", and while I understand its an open-ended question its still very frustrating that no one could at least scoff and point in the direction of a babies first server pdf)*

From a brand new windows instance Ive installed my development environment (mysql, visual code, node, ect) and ive run the app as I would on my local machine - which as expected, works on the local host.

but then when I try to access the server [AWS publicIP]/[app port] the app cant connect

So i researched how to do port forwarding on aws and opened up all traffic and made sure the EC2 instance was connected to a valid VCP and whatnot and still nothing

then I added rules in the windows firewall that allowed all traffic and still nothing

So then I looked into NGINX, installed it, localhost ran the test page properly, but when I try to connect to the public IP (with and without the port 80 attached) I cant get the test page to show up and im at a complete loss

any help would be very appreciated, ive been making software forever and I want to get into fullstack development but deployment beyond using one of those "made easy" services is almost impossible to someone who doesn't know the jargon